# Pandas repeated columns into new row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data in a csv which has some columns duplicated, and I want to create multiple rows which repeats some of the columns. I'm trying to do this using pandas in Python.

Take the following as an MWE. I import my data using `df = pandas.read_csv('my.csv')`, and have something that looks like the following:

```
a  b  c  c.1  c.2
1  2  3   4    5
6  7  8   9    0
```

As can be seen columns *a* and *b* are unique but *c* has multiple values. I want to split up the *c* values into separate rows, duplicating *a* and *b*, i.e. achieve the following:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
1  2  4
1  2  5
6  7  8
6  7  9
6  7  0
```

In the interest of not having to type too much I've left out a *d* column which is similarly duplicated but the solution should be versatile enough to accommodate this.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [426]: pd.lreshape(df, {'c':df.columns[df.columns.str.match('^c\.?\d?')]})
Out[426]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  6  7  8
2  1  2  4
3  6  7  9
4  1  2  5
5  6  7  0
```

Comment: @jezrael, yes, i think this is the best option

Answer (score 2):

Use `melt`:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['a','b'], value_name='c').drop('variable',1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  6  7  8
2  1  2  4
3  6  7  9
4  1  2  5
5  6  7  0
```

It's a little tricky to build a general case for multiple variables.  Here's a solution that's based on your case of having dupes for both `c` and `d`.  It still uses `melt()`, but then renames all the `c` variants to `c` and same for `d`.  Then it basically separates the `c` and `d` segments and merges them.  It's a little clunky.

```
df['d'] = df.c
df['d.1'] = df['c.1']
df['d.2'] = df['c.2']

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['a','b'])
df2.variable = df2.variable.str.replace('^(c|d).*', '\\1')
dupe_vars = ['c','d']

(df2.loc[df2.variable.eq('c')]
    .rename(columns={'value':'c'})
    .drop('variable',1)
    .reset_index(drop=True).merge(
        df2.loc[df2.variable.eq('d')]
           .rename(columns={'value':'d'})
           .drop('variable',1)
           .reset_index(drop=True), 
        left_index=True, right_index=True, on=['a','b']))

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  3
1  6  7  8  8
2  1  2  4  4
3  6  7  9  9
4  1  2  5  5
5  6  7  0  0
```

Comment: yeah, i think `pd.melt()` is the idiomatic solution here +1

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index(['a','b']).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',1).rename(columns={0:'c'})
Out[754]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
2  1  2  5
3  6  7  8
4  6  7  9
5  6  7  0
```